# How to set the default value without a related field in odoov11?

Tags: python, odoo

I would need to set the value of the `'overtime_w'` field as the default value for the `'overtime_w_edit'` field without a related field.

```
overtime_w = fields.Float(compute='_compute_t_overtime_w')
overtime_w_edit = fields.Float()
```

Comment: First guess: try to set `overtime_w_edit` to `overtime_w` in the compute method of it IF `overtime_w_edit` is still 0 (default value for float fields).

Comment: Like this?

@api.multi
    def _compute_t_overtime_w(self):
        self.overtime_w = sum((self.attendance_ids.mapped('overtime_50_numeric')))
        for record in self:
            need = record.overtime_w
            record.overtime_w_edit += need